# Opencart create custom admin api

Tags: rest, opencart-3

I have created a custom REST api to call the order api and get the order details, but it is redirecting me again to login page when I calling the api from browser and it throws error "Permission Denied". How to resolve it?

Comment: Post your code & error here properly. 
try this: Administrative Tools-> IIS Manager -> You Server Name -> Your site name -> Under HTTP features -> Default document -> Add MyDefaultPage.aspx

Comment: I am working on live server, actually I need to get the order details i.e. calling the getOrders() function for that I have created this api. Is there any way to call it directly from existing api?